# Display markers in the polygon I zoomed to

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, polygons

Here is my [example.](http://mini.hr/stanonline/test2.php)

I add some code, and when the page is loaded it's possible to see only polygons what's great but when I zoomed to the polygon with this function I get all markers but my dream was to get only markers in the polygon I zoomed to so I need to resolve this problem with containsLocation but don't know how.

```
function kmlShowPlacemark(pm) {
    if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon) {
        map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon.bounds);
        addMarker(45.374632, 14.425697,'<b>93 Feet East</b><br/>150 Brick Lane, London  E1 6RU&lt;br/&gt;7 Dec 2010 : Jenny &amp; Johnny&lt;br/&gt;');
        addMarker(45.374632, 14.425697,'<b>93 Feet East</b><br/>150 Brick Lane, London  E1 6RU&lt;br/&gt;7 Dec 2010 : Jenny &amp; Johnny&lt;br/&gt;');
        addMarker(45.348674, 14.386749,'<b>Adelphi Theatre</b><br/>The Strand, London  WC2E 7NA&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Love Never Dies');
        addMarker(45.35051, 14.351883,'<b>Adelphi Theatre</b><br/>The Strand, London  WC2E 7NA&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Love Never Dies');
        addMarker(45.319618, 14.501915,'<b>Albany, The</b><br/>240 Gt. Portland Street, London  W1W 5QU');
        addMarker(45.339893, 14.475479,'<b>Aldwych Theatre</b><br/>Aldwych, London  WC2B 4DF&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Dirty Dancing');
        addMarker(45.343513, 14.436684,'<b>Alexandra Palace</b><br/>Wood Green, London  N22&lt;br/&gt;30 Oct 2010 : Lynx All-Nighter');
        addMarker(45.330736, 14.434211,'<b>Stan F.La Guardia 10</b><br/>Najbolji stan na svijetu');
        addMarker(45.385431, 14.357071,'<b>sdas</b><br/>dfsada');
     } 
for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
 var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
 if (i == pm) {
   if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(null);
   if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(map);

 } else {
   if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(map);
   if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(null);
   }
}
}
```

The next problem was partially solved. When u press Show all polygons (Prikaži sve kvartove) it's called function showAll and it show u all polygons but it must show you all polygons without markers. I try with two methods but it doesn't work for me marker.setVisible(false); and marker.setMap(null); and than I load basic page top.location="test2.php"; how is possible to resolve this better?

```
function showAll() {
    top.location="test2.php";
    map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.bounds); //show all bounds
    map.setZoom(13);
   //marker.setVisible(false);
   //marker.setMap(null); 
   for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
       var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(map);
       if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(map);
   }
 }
```

I tried to hide markers but my way is not good because after my way I don't see any markers any more, here is how I do it:

```
function hideMarkers(){
    for(var i=0; i<hmarkers.length; i++){
        hmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
}    
<?
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poi_example");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $name=$row['name'];
    $lat=$row['lat'];
    $lon=$row['lon'];
    $desc=$row['desc'];
    echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc');\n");
    echo 'hideMarkers();'
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding all the markers to the map at the beginning (but hide them), keeping references to them in an array.  Then when the Polygon is clicked, process through the array testing if [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) is true:

```
function kmlShowPlacemark(pm) {
  if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon) {
    map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon.bounds);
    for (var i=0;i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(gmarkers[i].getPosition(),geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon)) {
         gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
      } else {
         gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
      }
    }
  } 

   for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
     var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
     if (i == pm) {
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(null);
       if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(map);

     } else {
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(map);
       if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(null);
       }
   }
}
```

(note: the example below doesn't hide the markers to start, because I wanted to know where they are, clicking on a polygon hides all the markers outside the polygon and shows (again) the ones inside it)
[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/mini_hr_stanonline_test_mouseover_20130313.html)

To hide the markers when the are first added remove the "map" option from the addMarker function:

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt,
        icon: icon
    });
// rest of the code stays the same.
```

Comment: It work great when I click on polygon, it's not possible to hide on start and than to show after clicking on a polygon?

Comment: I tried to hide markers (check my question) but it doesn't work when I click on a polygon, markers are still hided

Comment: Added how to do that to my answer.

Comment: Next step is to build input form for markers through database. Think this will be easy step for me. But one more thing is on my mind: when you click on some polygon you got  infowindow with the name of these polygon, is possible to put in this infowindow number of markers inside this polygon (same like marker cluster number) or to put this number (marker cluster number) on the polygon?

Comment: This is a different question. Yes it is possible.  For each of your polygons process through the array of markers counting the number contained, associate that number with the Polygon and display it.